# Unable to download a file using youtube_dl

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, bots, youtube-dl

I am trying to play music from a bot using ffmpeg and youtube_dl by making using of discord.py but it seems that I am unable to download the file

Here is my code:

```
voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

ydl_opts={
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'noplaylist': 'True',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec':'mp3',
        'preferredquality':'192',
    }],
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    print("Downloading audio now \n")
    ydl.download([url])

for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if file.endswith(".mp3"):
        name=file
        print(f"Renamed File: {file}\n")
        os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'), after=lambda e: print(f"{name} has finished playing"))
voice.is_playing()
voice.source=discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
voice.source.volume= 0.7

nname = name.rsplit("-", 2)
await ctx.send(f"Playing {nname}")
print("Playing \n")
```

Nothing seems to happen, the bot is not playing any music.

I am new to this, can anyone help?

Comment: How have you tried debugging the code so far? When you step line-by-line through it in a debugger, where does the behavior diverge from your expectations?

Comment: Yeah, no error is being shown in the terminal. However, "Downloading audio now" is not being printed